# Is there a numerical solution for a system of three 1st order nonlinear ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

How would I go about solving the following system of non-linear ODEs for $x(t),  y(t), z(t)$

$$x' = y $$
$$y'=\sin(x)+z$$ 
$$z'=y-z$$

I have the following initial conditions;

$$x(0) = 0$$  $$x'(0) = 0 $$

Comment: You are going to be left with a free parameter unless you specify an initial condition for $z(t)$.

Comment: Is there a numerical method that can be used that wouldn't require $z(t)$?the only condition for $z(t)$ that I know of is $z(0) \neq 0$

Comment: I don't know how you would numerically integrate without specifying $z(0)$. I am speaking of a finite difference scheme and if you wanted to include this free parameter $z(0)=\zeta_{0}$, then it would be incredibly inefficient to do so many of these computations symbolically.

Comment: Combining the three equations leads to :$$x'''+x''-(1+cosx)x'-sin(x)=0$$. Three boundary conditions are required for the solution bo be unique. Anyways, the ODE cannot be analytically solved on a closed form. Bytheway, $x(t)=y(t)=z(t)=0$ is a solution of the system of equations together with the given boundary conditions.

Comment: Do you have any other conditions? Maybe some endpoint condition. The solution to your problem is not unique, it depends on $z(0)$

Comment: @JJacquelin thank you for that, would it be possible for you to write it below as an answer with a few steps to the final equation so I can accept it please and again thank you for this you are a life saver!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only to make more obvious what was already obvious, as said in several comments :
$$z=y'-\sin(x)$$
$$z'=y''-\cos(x)x'$$
$$z'=y-z=y''-\cos(x)x'=y-(y'-\sin(x))$$
$$y''+y'-y-\cos(x)x'-\sin(x)=0$$
$$x'''+x''-x'-\cos(x)x'-\sin(x)=0$$
Numerical computation of $x(t)$ , $y(t)$ , $z(t)$ requires to state a third condition, for example $x''(0)$ , or $z(0)$, any numerical method used.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm having to guess at how this answers the Question ("is there a numerical solution for...").  If you are proposing to solve numerically the higher-order ODE show above for $x$, rather solving the system of first-order ODEs, this would be an intelligible approach.  However you should say this is what you mean, and argue (if possible) why you think the numerical solution is better done this way.  If nothing else such an Answer could highlight the "missing" initial condition already noted in the Comments on the Question itself.

Comment: @ hardmath : I am not doing here a scolar exercise. This is only an hint to somebody who asked me for this : " would it be possible for you to write it below as an answer with a few steps to the final equation ". That's all.

Comment: I thank you for creating content that will be useful to future Readers. +1